# Laravel 5 Login 401 from Unity WWW request Unauthorized JWT (Works in browser & Postman)

Tags: c#, laravel, unity-game-engine, laravel-5, jwt

**UPDATE: At the bottom**

Notes:

- JWT Auth
- Nginx
- Laravel 5
- Unity (request fails)
- Postman: works.
- Chrome: works.

I've done a lot of searching trying to find answers to this but to no avail.

I'm trying to create a script in unity which logs into my Laravel application and returns the auth token so I can use it to make API requests.  The token is returned correctly.

C# Code:

```
private IEnumerator SendLogin(string user, string pass, Action<bool, string> callback)
{
    // Build login Submission form.
    WWWForm formData = new WWWForm();
    formData.AddField("email", user);
    formData.AddField("password", pass);
    formData.AddField("_token", "W4d7JugbWRg4ZASe4qAPinJVgg35OeaYStgeE7dm");

    // Checking Username and password were read correctly (they are)
    Debug.Log("Username: " + user + " Password: " + pass);

    // Create Request
    WWW www = new WWW(loginServerUrl, formData);
    Debug.Log("Sending Login Info To Server.");

    // Wait for request to finish
    yield return www;

    // just incase?
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.15f);
        Debug.Log("Waiting for download to finish.");
    }

    // Check for errors
    if (www.error != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in www.responseHeaders)
        {
            Debug.Log(header.Key.ToString() + " Value: " + header.Value.ToString());
        }
        Debug.Log("Error On Request. To string:" + www.error.ToString());
        StopCoroutine(login_coroutine);
    }

    // Get Response
    string response = www.text;
    Debug.Log(response);

    // Parse JSON
    var json = JSON.Parse(www.text);
    Debug.Log("Json: " + json.ToString());
    Debug.Log("Response: " + response);


    if (callback != null)
    {
        callback(true, response);
    }
    StopCoroutine(login_coroutine);
}
```

Chrome Screenshots: 
[image: before]
[image: after login pressed]

Postman Screenshot:
[image: postman]

Unity Screenshots (inc. Console Logs):
[image: console log]
(URL is different, I get the same outcome on /login)

**EDIT:**
I edited the login controller to return the entered email and password as a response and I get some interesting results.
I also checked the access logs and there is a weird correlation.
"\u200b" is added onto the end of both of the username and password.

Logs:
192.168.178.80 - - [02/Feb/2018:11:03:47 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 401 12 "-" "UnityPlayer/2018.1.0b4 (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)" "-"
192.168.178.80 - - [02/Feb/2018:12:55:33 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 361 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" "-"

Postman: 
[image: console log]

Unity:
[image: console log]

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer. Please do not edit your question for this. Please post your solution as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity Was adding Zero Width Space at the end of the Username And Password. (Trim them with .TrimEnd('\u200b'))

```
WWWForm formData = new WWWForm();
formData.AddField("email", user.TrimEnd('\u200b'));
formData.AddField("password", pass.TrimEnd('\u200b'));
formData.AddField("_token", {{YOUR TOKEN}});
```

Answer (score 1):

WWWForm Data is not woking we have to use `List<IMultipartFormSection>` to make a form

```
 List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
 url = loginRoute;
 //form.AddField("email", "mail");
 //form.AddField("password", "skerasdas");
 formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("email", "prashant6j556i1asd@gmail.com"));
 formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("password", "skerasdas"));
```